# Formatting: Diacritics outside of Formulas

Tags: discussion

I recently tried to write the name of the French mathematician Gâteaux in the correct way, i.e. with a circumflex over the first 'a'.

Using MathJax formatting inside inline math or in formula, that is no problem, but how do I do that outside, not using MathJax?

Comment: Just type it in like any other text, without using MathJax or any other fancy things: Gâteaux. Or paste it from somewhere else if your keyboard doesn't easily permit entering an â.

Comment: In the latter way, you can also enter e.g. chinese text: 曼弗雷德·魏斯

Comment: I would revert to html, typing `G&acirc;teaux`.

Comment: A side note: SE search should return more-or-less the same results both for [Gâteaux](http://mathoverflow.net/search?q=G%C3%A2teaux) and [Gateaux](http://mathoverflow.net/search?q=Gateaux). Somewhat related post on meta.math.SE: [Searching for accented characters is too strict](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/8698).

Comment: Related older post on this meta: [LaTeX style accents in regular text](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/290)

Comment: Thanks to all commenters for the good tips!

Comment: And since I am posting lost of links perhaps two more from superuser will not do any harm. (I am sure many more entries like that can be found on various SE sites.) [Insert Unicode characters via the keyboard?](http://superuser.com/q/47420) and [How do I type accented characters in windows?](http://superuser.com/q/110605)